# Are Cookies a Security Risk?

Tags: php, security, cookies, sanitization, code-injection

Assume we have a website that asks the user for his name.

The website then stores this value in a cookie, and on the next page, retrieves it via PHP and uses it somehow (perhaps the page displays the name as text).

Could a user modify the cookie data to inject malicious code?  Should cookie data be sanitized as it's retrieved by the script?

(This is a hypothetical scenario.  Obviously a cookie wouldn't be necessary here.)

Comment: See [WP:Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) and general [`$_COOKIE`](http://php.net/_COOKIE) information in the manual ("handling external variables").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could a user modify the cookie data to inject malicious code? Should cookies be sanitized as they're retrieved by the script?

Inject malicious code?  Not PHP code, but you are right that you should sanitize cookie values before working with them.

Cookies can be easily modified, added and deleted by users and should be treated as untrusted user input.  They are just as prone to XSS and SQL injection vunlerabilities as any other user input.

Further, unless you're using SSL, cookies are just as prone to sniffing as GET or POST data in a request.  Malicious internet services can intercept or modify cookies.  Also see [Firesheep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep) for an example of how cookies can be misused and mistrusted.

Comment: if you "run" data from a cookie you are just crazy.

Comment: eh, lemme fix the wording of that phrase.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how cookie data could be manipulated for XXS?

Comment: Do you mean, say, `echo $_COOKIE['foo']`?  Actually, considering that cookies are browser-specific, it'd be highly silly for a user to XSS himself.  It'd also be silly for malicious internet service providers to modify cookies to do XSS, as, well, they can modify the content *anyway* so they'd may as well do it directly.

Comment: Sorry, but why not PHP code?  This conflicts with drrcknlsn's answer.

Comment: No user data can ever be executed on the server unless you take *explicit steps to do so* through a function that evaluates strings as code, like `eval`, `assert` and `create_function`, or if you're sloppy with the use of [variable variables](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and [variable functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).  Merely echoing cookie data back out to the user is *just* creating an XSS vulnerability, not creating a code injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 3):

There is no inherent security risk in using cookies.  The security risks come from your handling of the cookie data, and what data you store in the cookies.  If, for example, you do something like this:

```
<h3>Hello, <?php echo $_COOKIE['user']; ?>!</h3>
```

...then the user will be able to inject arbitrary code into your page (XSS vulnerability).  To fix this security problem, you must properly escape the cookie data for the HTML context:

```
<h3>Hello, <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['user']); ?>!</h3>
```

Comment: So it IS possible to inject executable PHP code in the first example?

Comment: @Peter: Yes, it is possible, but it's not because of the use of cookies.  It's because of the *lack* of proper data escaping.  The same vulnerability exists with POST, GET, SERVER, FILE, SESSION, etc. if you don't escape the data properly.

Answer (score 1):

All vars in PHP with $_ ($_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE, $_FILE, $_SESSION) in the front of the name should checked before you put them on the page or in a database.

You could use [`htmlentities( $str )`](http://php.net/htmlentities) to protected most of the injections.

Comment: `htmlentities` can maliciously mangle Unicode unless treated carefully.  `htmlspecialchars` provides the same level of protection against XSS without the character set shenanigans.

Comment: @Charles: The `htmlentities()` function takes an optional 3rd parameter to specify the character set.  It will only "maliciously mangle" your data if you don't use the proper settings.

Comment: While this is true, it also forces you to think about character encoding on *every single call*, which is cumbersome at best and an annoyance at worst.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are just another form of input from the client, in that a client can send you anything they want in a cookie and your app must not trust what is submitted in a cookie until you sanitize/validate it.

Good guidance on performing **data validation**, which should be properly applied to all inputs into your application, including cookies, is provided by OWASP and [can be found here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation). The short form is: do accept-known-good validation where you clearly define acceptable inputs and only accept those. Having a blacklist in addition to block known-bad patterns (in concert with a good accept-known-good approach, not to replace it) is a good idea too.