# mysql real escape string and Cookies

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sanitization, mysql-real-escape-string

Is there any reason this is bad form?  The only user input data on the page is

```
// Set username and password from cookies
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE["username"]);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['password']);
```

I am REALLY new to the idea of sanitizing.  Is there any reason this is a terrible way of doing things?

Comment: Why do you feel using cookies in this context? You must not.

Comment: Id love an explanation of why not...

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992415/are-cookies-a-security-risk

Comment: I think that you are getting very confused about when to use Cookies and when to use Session variables.  May read this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 1):

**NEVER, EVER** store users' data in cookies!

Here's what I suggest:

- store user's ID in cookie
- generate special token and hash+salt and store them in cookies
- store everything in database
- get data from cookies on every page load and try searching for them in database
- if not found, then logout a user
- change token on every page load

Comment: Can you explain to me what the issue is.  Storing the user's ID in the cookie is half of what im doing... the other half is storing a hashed version of their password?  Based on Lokesh's answer I think it might be better to use "base64" rather than hash... other than that whats the issue?

Comment: +1 One additional suggestion: Dump the `mysql_*` functions and switch to `PDO` or `mysqli` for database handling.

Comment: lol, @jeroen  That was originally what i was asking, if it was okay to use mysql...       But clearly i need to resolve this cookies are illegal thing first.

Comment: @user187680 don't store plain-text (or encrypted...) passwords anywhere, not on your server on not on the visitors computer.

Comment: @jeroen now im really lost.  If I don't have a hashed version of their pass on my server (in my sql database) how can i verify?

Comment: @user187680 Hashed is not the same as encrypted. Hashed (+salted) versions is exactly what you should store if you need to store them.

Comment: @user187680 I hope this will help: [PHP Secure Login Tips and Tricks](http://hungred.com/useful-information/php-secure-login-tips-and-tricks/)